# Mongo collections com o mesmo nome em bancos de dados diferentes

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorjs

Estou fazendo um protótipo em Meteor que necessitará se conectar a vários bancos de dados e precisa exportar para cada um dos bancos de dados uma mesma collection e não estou conseguindo fazer o publish das collections com nomes diferentes para diferenciar.

A ideia é, eu tenho vários bancos de dados e em todos existe a collection users, preciso fazer o publish de todas, cada uma com um nome.

**Do lado servidor**

```
// Usuários do banco de dados 1
var RemoteDatabase1 = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(dababaseUrl1);
var Users1 = new Mongo.Collection('users', { _driver: RemoteDatabase1, _suppressSameNameError: true });

Meteor.publish('users1', function() {
  var UserCursor1 = Users1.find({});

  // this automatically observes the cursor for changes,
  // publishes added/changed/removed messages to the 'people' collection,
  // and stops the observer when the subscription stops
  Mongo.Collection._publishCursor(UserCursor1, this, 'users1');

  this.ready();
});

// Usuários do banco de dados 2
var RemoteDatabase2 = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(dababaseUrl2);
var Users2 = new Mongo.Collection('users', { _driver: RemoteDatabase2, _suppressSameNameError: true });

Meteor.publish('users2', function() {
  var UserCursor2 = Users2.find({});

  // this automatically observes the cursor for changes,
  // publishes added/changed/removed messages to the 'people' collection,
  // and stops the observer when the subscription stops
  Mongo.Collection._publishCursor(UserCursor2, this, 'users2');

  this.ready();
});
```

**Do lado Cliente**

```
// Usuários do banco de dados 1
const Users1 = new Mongo.Collection('users1');
Meteor.subscribe('users1');

var Users1Values = Users1.find({});
console.log(Users1Values);
Users1Values.forEach((user1Value) => {
  console.log(user1Value);
});

// Usuários do banco de dados 2
const Users2 = new Mongo.Collection('users2');
Meteor.subscribe('users2');

var Users2Values = Users2.find({});
console.log(Users2Values);
Users2Values.forEach((user2Value) => {
  console.log(user2Value);
});
```

O problema é que mesmo existindo dados em ambos os bancos de dados, os dados, do lado cliente as collections ficam vazias.

**Qual seria a forma correta de fazer o publish e subscribe nesse caso?**

Já tentei as abordagens presentes nas repostas às perguntas:

- [How can i publish the same collection under different names in a Meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267241/10535111)
- [Publishing/subscribing multiple subsets of the same server collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663746/10535111)
- [Meteor publish/subscribe strategies for unique client-side collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544094/10535111)

Porém todos resultaram em collections vazias do lado cliente.

Comment: Boas Alex, tente fazer `return` do cursor dentro do `Meteor.publish`

Answer (score 0):

@Alex tenta isso (Código abaixo) talvez possa te ajudar.

Básicamente o que fiz foi criar uma `Collection` que vai auxiliar na comunicação do *server* - mongo e *client* - minimongo. Isto Porque, quando se faz um `subscribe` o meteor diz ao servidor para enviar registros para o cliente. O cliente armazena esses registros em coleções Minimongo locais, com o mesmo nome do argumento de coleção usado na publicação.

> O cliente verá um documento se o documento estiver atualmente no conjunto de registros publicado de qualquer uma de suas assinaturas.
>   Se várias publicações publicarem um documento com o mesmo _id para a
>   mesma coleção, os documentos serão mesclados para o cliente. Se os
>   valores de qualquer um dos campos de nível superior entrarem em
>   conflito, o valor resultante será um dos valores publicados, escolhido
>   arbitrariamente.
>
> Atualmente, quando várias assinaturas publicam o mesmo documento,
>   apenas os campos de nível superior são comparados durante a mesclagem.
>   Isso significa que, se os documentos incluírem subcampos diferentes do
>   mesmo campo de nível superior, nem todos estarão disponíveis no
>   cliente.

```
// Nao Guarda na DB, porque nunca chamamos o metodo insert.
export const UsersAll = new Mongo.Collection('users.all');

// Server code
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Usuários do banco de dados 1
  const RemoteDatabase1 = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(dababaseUrl1);
  const Users1 = new Mongo.Collection('users1', {
    _driver: RemoteDatabase1,
    _suppressSameNameError: true
  });

  // Usuários do banco de dados 2
  const RemoteDatabase2 = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(dababaseUrl2);
  const Users2 = new Mongo.Collection('users2', {
    _driver: RemoteDatabase2,
    _suppressSameNameError: true
  });


  Meteor.publish("users.all", function usersAll(collectionId) {
    check(collectionId, String);

    let self = this;
    let newNode;

    // Formar uma lista exclusiva de utilizadores
    // _.union - https://underscorejs.org/#union
    newNode = _.union(Users1.find({}).fetch(), Users2.find({}).fetch());

    self.added('users.all', collectionId, {
      users: newNode
    });

    return self.ready();

  });
}

// client code

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  const collectionId = Random.id(); // Retornar um identificador único
  Meteor.subscribe('users.all',collectionId,onReady);

  function onReady() {
    var usersAll = UsersAll.findOne({_id: collectionId});
    usersAll = usersAll.users;
    console.log('usersAll: ', usersAll);
  }
}
```